# How do I pass a block to the Devise create method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Im using [devise token auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) (which inherently just uses Devise) and I'm trying to modify the `resource` object before it gets saved upon user registration. The `create` method, as defined in the source and explained in user documentation has a `yield resource if block_given?` line, yet, the following code doesnt work as expected

```
class RegistrationsController < DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController       
    def create                                                                 
          puts "this works"                                                    
          super do |resource|                                                  
            puts "this doesnt work"                                            
          end                                                                  
    end                                                                        
end
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Any error message or this fails silently ?

Comment: According to the current source on GitHub, `DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController#create` does not yield `resource` anywhere. Are you perhaps confusing it with another create method?

Comment: @RobWagner You're right

Comment: Update to this: `DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController#create` actually does yield a block if the resource is successfully saved now. See: https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/00fa5f4507da806f66664787745086ce404d95b4/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/registrations_controller.rb#L41

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/registrations_controller.rb

This base controller doesn't have block invocation.

Probably you meant https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb

It has block invocation, but it'll not work, because DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController will not pass block to it.

You need some other way to achieve what you want.

Probably paste code from DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController to your custom controller, or fork DeviseTokenAuth gem and patch it.

Don't forget to make PR